# How to resolve resource is not available in Restful WebService

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey, web.xml

I have created a REST webservice 'JSONService' ( using Jersey implementation  JAX-RS) with a POST method and created 'JerseyClientPost'.
What I am trying to achieve is to send a POST from my JerseyClientPost. Getting all values into a 'player' object and sending along with response back. But while trying to send the POST request from the postman, it throws

```
HTTP Status 404 - Not Found, The requested resource is not available.
```

Any pointers to address this problem will be much appreciated ?

Request Url : http://localhost:8080/WeekendSoccer/test/register/create

Following are my environment details:
*JDK 1.7.0_79,
Tomcat Server v7.0,
Jersey (jaxrs-ri-2.25.1),
Web.xml*

**//REST Resource is given below**

```
package webService;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;
import dto.RegisterPlayer;

@Path("/register")
public class JSONService {
    @POST
    @Path("/create")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createPlayerInJSON(RegisterPlayer player) {     
        String result = "Player Created : " +player;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();     
    }

}
```

**//Below is the Jersey Client Post**

```
package dao;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class JerseyClientPost {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            RegisterPlayer player = new RegisterPlayer();
            player.setName("Link");
            player.setEmail("link@test.com");
            player.setCompany("Test Ltd");  

            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig().register( LoggingFilter.class ));
            WebTarget webTarget 
              = client.target("http://localhost:8080/WeekendSoccer/test");
            WebTarget playerWebTarget 
              = webTarget.path("/register/create");
            Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder 
              = playerWebTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            Response response 
              = invocationBuilder
              .post(Entity.entity(player,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));          

            if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                   + response.getStatus());
            }
            System.out.println(response.getStatus());
            System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));          


          } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          }

        }

}
```

**// RegisterPlayer model class with getters, setters**

```
public class RegisterPlayer implements Serializable{    

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String company; 

    public RegisterPlayer()
    {

    }

    public RegisterPlayer(String name, String email, String company)
    {
    super();

    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.company = company;

    }    

    public String getName()
    {
    return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
    this.name = name;
    }
     ....
     }
```

// Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WeekendSoccer</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Register Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>webService</param-value>        
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Register Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>JSON Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>dao</param-value>        
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>JSON Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**//Listed all jars**

```
aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar
gson-2.2.2.jar
hk2-api-2.5.0-b32.jar
hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar
hk2-utils-2.5.0-b32.jar
jackson-annotations-2.3.2.jar
jackson-core-2.3.2.jar
jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar
jackson-jaxrs-base-2.3.2.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.3.2.jar
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.3.2.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.inject-2.5.0-b32.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar
jersey-client.jar
jersey-common.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
jersey-container-servlet.jar
jersey-entity-filtering-2.17.jar
jersey-guava-2.25.1.jar
jersey-media-jaxb.jar
jersey-media-json-jackson-2.17.jar
jersey-server.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar
org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar
osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
persistence-api-1.0.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:8080/WeekendSoccer/rest/register/create`?

Comment: Cassio: Yes I have tried that from postman, it is giving me an error code 400 bad request

Comment: So if the server says it's a bad request, fix your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure, why do you have following mapping in web.xml ? As theren't any servlet class associated with this servlet name. You should removed them

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>JSON Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I see you have following entries and they do have servlet class associated.

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Register Service</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

That means, you target url **should be**

```
http://localhost:8080/WeekendSoccer/rest/register/create
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:8080/WeekendSoccer/test/register/create
```

Comment: Removed the mapping, still it doesn't work, now the player is receiving as null

Comment: @ljs You didn't get what I meant, I said, there is no point of having that mapping. So, you keep or remove, it shouldn't matter. So, I said, better remove it. Now, actual issue was request url, which I told.

Comment: @ljs Note, if you are getting `null` means you are getting response and that means it is hitting to server and server responded. And that was your actual question (*The requested resource is not available*)

Comment: Now I have even tried with correct request url in postman with following json input data-  { "name": "Link", "email": "link@test.com", "company": "Test Ltd" }, but error displaying in postman with HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type - The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method

Comment: @ljs Again, I'm repeating same. You are request is reaching to server, but you have not coded correctly at server side and that's the reason you are getting all those error. Since, you are actual issue was resolved, you need to closed this by accepting and upvoting this answer and create new post with specific details

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I have never tested your client side code but I guess your problem is about server side and tested in ***Postman***. you should add `@XmlRootElement` annotation in your pojo class *RegisterPlayer* like that:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class RegisterPlayer implements Serializable{    

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String company; 

    public RegisterPlayer()
    {

    }

    public RegisterPlayer(String name, String email, String company)
    {
    super();

    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.company = company;

    }
```

and added these dependencies in **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.3</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

If you already have these jars it is fine. It works for me right now. I hope it helps to you.

```
jackson-core-2.9.3.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar
jersey-bundle-1.19.4.jar
jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
json-20170516.jar
jersey-server-1.19.4.jar
jersey-core-1.19.4.jar
jersey-multipart-1.19.4.jar
mimepull-1.9.3.jar
jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar
jackson-databind-2.7.0.jar
```

Comment: By the way why do we need to add the @XmlRootElement annotation in POJO class ? I will give try anyway. 
I don't have a pom.xml, only have the web.xml file. While creating a project I have choose the normal webservice option and my project is not in spring boot.

Comment: without `@XmlRootElement` annotation gives me application/jason not found error. Normally this annotation is added for xml conversion. updated my answer with jars that i have instead pom.xml

Comment: I have added the jars and added '@XmlRootElement' annotation. Now I am getting the 'player' 'null' while sending the post request

Comment: How do you send request. with your client ?Could you please test your server side code using postman like that?

Comment: Using postman I am sending request. Giving this url in the postman and select POST option. Its hitting server side and giving the player = null

Comment: Also added  following if condition in Resource area`if(player == null){
         return Response.status(400).entity("Please add player details !!").build();
     }` and its giving me "Please add player details" in postman body raw tab

Comment: Pls see the input given in postman {
  "name": "Link",
  "email": "link@test.com",
  "company": "Test Ltd"
}

Comment: It looks great. not sure why you have null.

Comment: Ok I will stop server, clean, close Eclipse, close postman and restart again, will try that way and update

Comment: Now it give me error HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type ---
 The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method and

Comment: you have still @XmlRootElement annotation on your pojo?

Comment: Yes I do have it